# Saving files in a container

Tags: c#, file, containers

I know this has been asked before, but I haven't really found the solution I need.

What I want is create a container with my own extension (let's call it .pmap) where I store stuff like xml files, png files and so on. Basically said: a zip, which is **not** a zip

I don't really want to store the data of all files into one files and read them out... I just want a container. (maybe something like .rxproj, if you know RPG Maker)

Anybody ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just create a ZIP? Change its extension if you feel like it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I don't really want to store the data of all files into one files and read them out...'?  What do you want to do that isn't this?  As this is basically what a zip file / any sort of composite/compression file format is.  Are you just saying you want some API around the file so it doesn't appear to be a single file?  If you don't like ZIP you could try CAB: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CABCompressExtract.aspx

Comment: Ok, what properties of zip files do you not want?

Comment: One of the reasons is that I want it to encrypt/decrypt myself (I know Zips can do that). The other thing is, that this project is going to be a little bit of a big thing, so writing an own container is (imho) the best solution.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is, IMO, never the best solution.

Comment: It'd be reasonably easy to do if the files doesn't have to change after the first write (A map of the files location, then data). If you need to deal with file resizes within the container, etc; it gets more complicated. Try to describe exactly why you need (and why you are not satisfied with ZIP or similar).

Comment: @Kevin, a big thing doesn't make reinventing the wheel the best solution.  Just use a zip library.

Comment: If you need your own encryption, you can easily just encrypt the zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own container format (archive) instead of using an existing format, the anatomy would look something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Header (checksum, magic number, etc)                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Manifest (list of file metadata like file names and offsets)                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| File 1 header (usually file size)                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| File 1 content                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ...                                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| File (n) header (usually file size)                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| File (n) content                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you don't care about making your format easily consumable by different platforms, you can create classes encapsulating the container, ensure they're serializable, then use serialization/deserialization for converting the container to a stream (`BinaryFormatter` is one option for converting objects to bytes).

If you need to add compression or encryption, you would then wrap this archive inside other envelopes (adding headers/footers as necessary to specify needed info about the compression or encryption).

Answer (score 0):

if your intension is abstraction and you dont want third parties to easily access / know wats your binary data in the container "AND" if you have specific constraints on what shared libraries to use then it makes sense! else would stick with others opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old question, but figured I'd throw another option in to the mix for anyone else who stumbles over this question looking for solutions (like myself)...

Maybe use the Microsoft Compound Document File Format? [OpenMCDF](http://openmcdf.sourceforge.net/) should make life easier.

> OpenMCDF is a 100% managed .net component that allows client
>   applications to manipulate COM structured storage files, also known as
>   Microsoft Compound Document Format files.